# Starting MySQL after installing MySQL 5.5 from .rpm

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-11.04

I m using Ubuntu 11.04. I have installed MySQL server and client ver 5.5.13.

The problem I have is actually to start MySQL after installing it from the `.rpm` package obtained from the Oracle site.

I m not able to find any guide for configuring MySQL after completing its installation. I installed it using alien.

Comment: Installing rpm packages on Debian based system is a bad practice. You should use packages provided by your system. Using "apt-cache search mysql" to get the list of available mysql packages, and "apt-get install mysql-server-5.5 mysql-client-5.5" to install MySQL packaged by Ubuntu/Debian maintainers. If this is a production server, it is even more of a bad idea to use RPM.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu has its own MySQL build you could use, you can install it through apt-get. [This article discusses that](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) and some typically related topics too.

I don't know how the RPM you installed is intended to work, but generally in later versions of Ubuntu, you can use the "service" command to control services. In your case, I'd try:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

That should start the mysql service, but, like I said, I don't know for sure what the RPM you installed really does.

I think you really ought to look at the link I provided. You may also quite benefit from installing phpmysql - which can be helpful for administering your mysql server, once you have it running.

Comment: It gives "Starting MySQL
. * The server quit without updating PID file (/var/lib/mysql/home-PC.pid)". So i guess there is something on the configuration part missing. I have tried creating mysql user and group but no use.

Comment: So can anyone help me to start up MySQL.

Comment: Are you still running on the rpm version you installed?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working after doing the following:

```
sudo alien -i MySQL-server*.rpm --script

sudo alien -i MySQL-client*.rpm --script

mysql -u root password xxxxxxxx

sudo apt-get install libaio1 libaio-dev

sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant &
```

Then check if the MySQL daemon has started or not:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql status
```

You can then get a MySQL prompt with the following and entering your password:

```
/usr/bin/mysql -u root -p
```